# Doing a simple substraction and elminiation of values right after

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been tyring to get a table to do a simple "taxing" system for a little game I work with sometimes. It's supposed to basically substract a money value from one row, and save it as a different value in that same row.

The table is basically

```
Name - Money - Tax - ETC - ETC - ETC
```

Those are the only 3 values I really want to touch with the query, but I have no idea how to make it happen. 
It's supposed to Create a value in tax that is `Tax` = `Money` * 0.10

Then it's supposed to call forth a different action, where It deducts that `Tax` from the Money itself, and not change anything else.
The goal there is to later make it add to a different `Name` field the tax from all of the affected rows. Yes, I have been looking through the site, but can't seem to find an answer. Soo, someone please save me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried an `update`?

```
update t
    set tax = money * 0.1,
        money = money * 0.9
    where name = ?;
```

Comment: The goal is to basically make it substract the tax from the money field.
UPDATE t SET money = money - tax WHERE name = X
Yes, that works to do the actual billing of the "tax".
But, in the term of it, I want to also make what was substracted by "tax" be added to another row. 
As in, a different name. Like Y.